# Ruby count array unique elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a statistics module for my library class that shows the most popular books and top readers

```
module Statistics
  def top_reader
    orders_grouped = orders.group_by(&:reader)
    tab = orders_grouped.max_by(3) { |_k, v| v.count }.map(&:first)
    puts "#{tab.map(&:name).join(', ')} - are the top readers"
  end

  def top_book
    orders_grouped = orders.group_by(&:book)
    tab = orders_grouped.max_by(2) { |_k, v| v.count }.map(&:first)
    puts "#{tab.map(&:title).join(', ')} - are the top books"
  end
end
```

That's how i get top reader and top book
I need to get amount of unique readers of the top book now, i tried to do it this way but it's not working correctly and the code are not very clean

```
  def top_book_readers
    puts @orders.select { |order| books.include? order.book }.uniq(&:reader).size
  end
```

Expected result is just the amount of unique readers that purchased top book

Edit:

```
  def top_book_readers
    orders_grouped = orders.group_by(&:book)
    top_orders_grouped = orders_grouped.max_by(1) { |_k, v| v.count }

    top_orders_grouped.each do |book, orders|
      num_readers = orders.map(&:reader).uniq.count
      puts "#{book.title} has #{num_readers} readers"
    end
  end
```

This works now, number of readers of top books are also configurable

Comment: Do you want to get the readers of the top _book_, or the top _two books_ as produced by your `top_book` method?

Comment: It appears you want something like `@orders.group_by { ... }.count { |_,v| v.size == 1 }`.

Comment: @maxpleaner i want to get readers of the top books i get. But as you can see the number of top books is configurable. Would appreciate if you could also help with 1 top book readers

Answer (score 2):

You can re-use some of that `group_by` logic from the other methods.

```
orders_grouped = orders.group_by(&:book)
top_orders_grouped = orders_grouped.max_by(2) { |_k, v| v.count }
```

Then to get the readers from the `top_orders_grouped`, you just get the unique `reader` values:

```
top_orders_grouped.each do |book, orders|
  num_readers = orders.map(&:reader).uniq.count
  puts "#{book} has #{num_readers} readers"
end
```

I should also mention, it's usually a good idea to make your methods return *data* instead of only printing output. This enables you to re-use the methods more easily.

Comment: Most of the time [`#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-map) + [`#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten) = [`#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) (that is, if you expect to flatten 1 level)

Comment: But i just need to get the number, not an array. For example: "top book was purchased by #{top_book_readers} readers" And number would be an expected result. It's an application

Comment: Seems like offloading the group and limit to the database would be a far better option IMO.

Answer (score 2):

If understood correctly, it should work like this:

```rb
# same like yours
top_books = orders.
  group_by(&:book).
  max_by(3) { |_k, v| v.count }.
  map(&:first)

# Hash of { <Book 1> => 30, <Book 2> => 10 }
reader_count_per_book = top_books.
  map { |book| [book, book.readers.uniq.count] }.
  to_h

# Or: uniq readers, that read at least one of the top books
uniq_readers_of_top_books = top_books.flat_map(&:readers).uniq.count
```

In general, if you have a database attached, and using ActiveRecord (your question is tagged as Rails), then it might be better to do all the work in sql (without knowning about your models/relationships/column names):

```rb
top_books = Order.
  joins(:book).
  order('count(orders.id) desc').
  limit(3).
  group("books.id").
  count

uniq_readers_of_top_books = Book.
  joins(:readers).
  where(id: top_books.keys).
  count('distinct readers.id')

reader_count_per_book = Book.
  joins(:readers).
  where(id: top_books.keys).
  group('books.title').
  count('distinct readers.id')
```